# remove numbers from a list less than variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm still early into learning to code, so sorry if the code is wonky...
I'm making a number guessing game that guesses based on a first guess from two numbers the user gives and then puts those numbers into a list ascending. then my issue, i want to remove numbers lower/higher from my first guess then just do random.choice(list) code to follow....

```
import random
print("\nLets see if I can guess the number you're thinking.\nI've got some questions first")
tryNumber=1
trys=int(input("How many trys will you let me have? "))
numberRangeLow=int(input("What is the lowest number I can guess?: "))
numberRangeHigh=int(input("And the highest?: "))

print("\nSo I have",str(trys),"trys")
print("And the number is between",str(numberRangeLow),"and",str(numberRangeHigh)+".\n")
firstGuess=random.randint(numberRangeLow, numberRangeHigh)
numbers=[]
nums=[]
while numberRangeLow < numberRangeHigh+1:
    numbers.append(numberRangeLow)
    nums.append(numberRangeLow)
    numberRangeLow+=1 

while tryNumber < trys:
    print("Is your number", str(firstGuess), "?")
    answer=input("Enter 'higher', 'lower' or correct (Case-Sensitive)")
    if answer == "higher":
        numbers.remove('''nums >= firstGuess''')
        firstGuess=random.choice(numbers)
        print("Is your number", str(firstGuess), "?")
```

I'm not comfortable with functions just yet which is why it's so much. once I get this perfectly ill change it to calling functions for the whole thing. -hopefully-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, `while numberRangeLow < numberRangeHigh+1: do stuff` is basically the same as `range`.
For the same result, you can use `numbers = range(numberRangeLow, numberRangeHigh + 1)`, which will build the list for you.

You also don't need to warn about it being case sensitive, if you use `str.lower()` it'll automatically put it into lower case. For example, you could do `if answer.lower() == "higher"`.

To remove numbers, you can do [list slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation). For example, if you have `a = [1, 2, 3, 4]`, and it's lower than 3, you can get the index of 3 by using `a.index(3)`, which in this case, will give 2.
By then cutting off anything higher than this index with `a[2:]`, you have removed any higher numbers than 3.

Here's a quick update to your code doing the bits I mentioned.

```
trys=int(input("How many trys will you let me have? "))
numberRangeLow=int(input("What is the lowest number I can guess?: "))
numberRangeHigh=int(input("And the highest?: "))
print("\nSo I have",str(trys),"trys")
print("And the number is between",str(numberRangeLow),"and",str(numberRangeHigh)

#New bits:
numbers = range(numberRangeLow, numberRangeHigh + 1)
for i in range(trys):
    guess = random.choice(numbers)
    print("Is your number", str(guess), "?")
    answer = input("Enter 'higher', 'lower' or 'correct'").lower()
    if answer == 'correct':
        break
    elif answer == 'higher':
        list_index = numbers.index(guess)
        numbers = numbers[list_index + 1:]
    elif answer == 'lower':
        list_index = numbers.index(guess)
        numbers = numbers[:list_index]
```

I rearranged the last part of the code so you didn't have 2 copies of the random choice. Also for the record, it's seen as better practice to `name_variables_like_this` and `notLikeThis`.

Edit: Kevins way is slightly different from mine, a simple comparison would be assuming you have written the numbers down on paper, this way would rip the paper in half and discard one part, whereas Kevins way would be writing it out again on a fresh sheet of paper, so you get more control, but it's a bit slower.

Edit 2:
Since I'm bored, I wrote it how I'd do it with a function (with some comments). Bear in mind it's python 2 not python 3 I'm using so copy + paste won't work for you.

```
def number_guess(tries, low, high):

    #Error if low is more than or the same as high
    if low >= high:
        raise ValueError('invalid range')

    #Build number list
    num_list = range(low, high + 1)
    print 'I have got {} tries'.format(tries)
    print 'And the number is between {} and {}'.format(low, high)

    for i in range(tries):
        guess = random.choice(num_list)
        print 'Is {} your number?'.format(guess)
        answer = input('Enter higher, lower or correct').lower()

        #Empty answer
        if not answer:
            continue

        #Correct answer
        if answer[0] in ('c', 'y'):
            print 'I guessed in {} tries'.format(i)
            return True

        #Number is higher
        if answer[0] == 'h':
            list_index = num_list.index(guess)
            num_list = num_list[list_index + 1:]

        #Number is lower
        elif answer[0] == 'l':
            list_index = num_list.index(guess)
            num_list = num_list[:list_index]

    #If it hits this point there are no tries left
    print 'I failed to guess'
    return False

tries = int(input('How many tries will you let me have?' ))
low = int(input('What is the lowest number I can guess?' ))
high = int(input('And what is the highest?' ))

success = number_guess(tries, low, high)
```

Comment: so, numbers=numbers[list_index + 1:]... where do i look for this stuff,

Comment: Click on the link for list slicing, it gives a basic example that will be better explained than my attempt :P  Basically, `[a:b]` means skip the first `a` and last `b` values, so `[a:]` just means cut off the first `a` values, and doesn't do anything to the end.

Answer (score 0):

Change `numbers.remove('''nums >= firstGuess''')` to `numbers.remove(firstGuess)` You also need to take into account the numbers that are greater than your first guess, so you have to delete the ones before it. `numbers = ([x for x in numbers if x > firstGuess])` should do the trick.

```
while tryNumber < trys:
    print("Is your number", str(firstGuess), "?")
    answer=input("Enter 'higher', 'lower' or correct (Case-Sensitive)")
    if answer == "higher":
      numbers = ([x for x in numbers if x > firstGuess])
      firstGuess=random.choice(numbers)
```

This should get you started.

Comment: what exactly is the " x for x in numbers " do? I understand if x greater than firstGuess